# vSphere Replication of a virtual machine showing huge deltas being replicated

Tags: sql-server, virtual-machine, replication, vsphere

We have vSphere Replication (V8.5) of a virtual machine with SQL Server 2017 Enterprise edition showing huge deltas being replicated to the backup site.

One drive in question is a 1.4 TB drive with a 1.1 TB Filestream database showing deltas of 1.4 TB being replicated to the backup site.

Are there any specific SQL settings I need to reduce these deltas?  I know the data written is less than 10 GB for the whole week.

Any other ideas I can throw at our SAN people?

Thanks

Comment: Check your maintenace jobs.  If you rebuild your indexes frequently it will churn the data in the data files.

Comment: Thanks.  I have disabled the index rebuild and integrity jobs today.  Will see what is produces.

Comment: Quick update.  Windows Task Manager has a way to track data read and written and looks like the SQL Service has written 720 GB of data over the last 25 days since a reboot.